Does PyTorch support matrix multiplication between quantized tensors with different quantization schemes?
I'm encountering an issue when trying to perform matrix multiplication with nnq.functional.linear between quantized tensors in PyTorch using different quantization schemes. Specifically, when both tensors are quantized using torch.quantize_per_tensor, the matrix multiplication works as expected. However, when one of the tensors is quantized using torch.quantize_per_channel, the operation fails with a RuntimeError.
Here's a simplified example I've tried:
import torch
import torch.nn.quantized as nnq


x = torch.tensor([-2., 2.]).reshape(1, 2)
w = torch.tensor([1., 2.]).reshape(2, 1)

xq = torch.quantize_per_tensor(x, scale=2.0, zero_point=0, dtype=torch.quint8)
wq = torch.quantize_per_tensor(w, scale=1.0, zero_point=0, dtype=torch.qint8)

yq = nnq.functional.linear(xq, wq.T)

In this case, both xq and wq are quantized using the torch.quantize_per_tensor function, and the matrix multiplication using nnq.functional.linear works as expected.
However, when I change wq to use torch.quantize_per_channel:
wq = torch.quantize_per_channel(w, scales=torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0]), zero_points=torch.tensor([0, 0]), dtype=torch.qint8, axis=0)

The matrix multiplication fails with an error.
RuntimeError: Setting strides is possible only on uniformly quantized tensor

My questions:

Why does matrix multiplication using nnq.functional.linear not work with per-tensor quantized tensor and per-channel quantized tensor?
Is it possible to perform matrix multiplication between quantized tensors with different quantization schemes without dequantizing and requantizing?

Additional information

PyTorch version: 2.2.2+cu121
Python version: 3.8.19

